# Is it fair to ask that a question be moved to the community wiki after it is closed?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, closed-questions

Hi!

For a reason I disagree with, one of my questions on StackOverflow was closed very quickly (I'm a little biased since I asked the question, but still, I think it should have remained open).

Is it fair to ask that a question be moved to the community wiki after it was closed? If that is fair, then what is the proper mechanism to make that happen:

1. Add a comment to the thread requesting it?
2. Edit the original post requesting it such that the post pops back up to the top of recent questions?
3. Some other way?

Thanks.

Oh, and if you are interested in the thread that I believe was mistakenly closed, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088049/good-book-holder-for-decent-sized-programming-books-closed

Answer (score 4):

Generally, things that should be moved to community wiki will have a torrent of comments saying "This should be CW".

For questions which are 'subjective and argumentative' there are some of them which might actually be good candidates for community wiki if they were refactored to edit out all the possible flamebait in them. However, the way the community usually manages this is that if a user edits out all the problems, then it may get re-opened, or they can try to reformat it so much as to be unrecognizable and try again.

In YOUR case, your question wasn't closed as "S & A", it was closed as "NPR" because it is in no way programming related. Similar to "How much is on your desk?" or "What is your Programmer Ringtone?" these are questions which you can ask to programmers, but they really don't have to do with programming. Even if your question was initially CW, then it would likely have been closed.

**EDIT**

Since you asked a question in your title that I didn't explicitly answer. **YES** it is FAIR to ask that they re-open it so you can move it to CW, but generally, the answer will be no, because moderators often-times (not always) would give you a chance or a warning to move it to CW first, before they vote to close. In your case, the CW-ness was not the contested part.

Comment: Fair enough devinb. I just figured that if a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon was fair game (at least for the wiki), I thought mine would be fair game too. To be totally honest, I am not terribly upset that my question was closed -- as you can see in my SO post, I knew there was a chance it would be -- I just thought the wiki might help give me an answer to my question :-)

Comment: That's fair, but you're a little newer to SO, and you weren't there for the formative times. Questions like that used to make it more often, but gradually the community evolved, and so those kind of questions aren't tolerated anymore. 

On a side note, using the 'he got away with it, so I should too' is a completely fallacious argument. If A murders someone and doesn't get caught, it does NOT make it acceptable for B to then murder someone. The fact that there are other questionable posts doesn't make it okay for you to ADD to the problem. It's more of an argument for CLOSING that one.

Comment: I have been around SO as a member for 7 months (only 2 less than Rich B) and as a viewer since inception. I just don't answer as many questions.

Anyway, I wasn't trying to use the "he did it so should I" argument. At least didn't want to come across that way. I was just saying, that I found my question programming related enough to possibly justify at least a wiki entry.

Comment: @Joel: What is programming related about it? Remove 'programming' from it, and it is still just a question about how to hold big books.

Comment: Rich B, if you read my one of my comments on the SO question about the book holder, I made an observation (wrongly or rightly) that a primary goal of StackOverflow was to increase programmer productivity -- with the primary means of doing that by answering technical programming questions. However, I did say that there are some maybe not so technical questions that programmers have that if answered correctly could also improve their productivity. And, yes, I thought my question was programming related enough...I explicitly said I wanted to learn a programming language by writing code.

Comment: @Joel: Again, not programming related.

Comment: Rich B, where did your answer to the question I raised in this thread go?? You know, where this whole "salutation" thing started? It is gone. Did you delete it? If so, why?

Anyway (and not that this will make any sense to anyone since your answer is gone), I think you should have stuck with your guns with your original answer. You told me explicitly that your original answer of (a) and (b) was your answer and that's that. I thought it was ridiculous, but I respect that. You didn't need to add the (c) or the (d) because you were getting down voted.

Comment: @Joel: I think you probably take some time and get used to the basic ways that SO works. You seem to be lacking some of the basic ideas. You can get started here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sofaq-official&sort=votes

Comment: @Rich B, I hadn't though you hit the greater than 5 down vote threshold yet (assuming that was the reason). My mistake. I apologize for not realizing.

Comment: @Joel Marcey: The problem is that your question is easily applicable to any domain that wants to hold open a book. Sure you want to apply this knowledge to learning a new programming language, but it is roughly equivalent to asking how to build a house so you can program under a roof. The programming part of it is irrelevant. You don't ask programmers how to build a house even if they all live in one, you ask carpenters.

Comment: @Toast, That is a fair perspective. And again, I am not holding any ill will that the question was closed. I figured that could happen. That's why I asked this wiki question to see if that would work.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if a question is closed, the author (mods too) should be able to reopen it as CW (community wiki) or move it here to the meta site.  It seems like the author's only option is to delete it or hope that enough people come in and vote to reopen.